# Time series data input to NN using Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, keras

Before getting into the code, a little bit of description of the data:

Time series with 14 features, but we are focused only on forecasting the temperature which is at index 2. Also, the given data is at 10 minute intervals:

```
["Date Time","p (mbar)","T (degC)","Tpot (K)","Tdew (degC)","rh (%)","VPmax (mbar)","VPact (mbar)","VPdef (mbar)","sh (g/kg)","H2OCmmol/mol)","rho (g/m**3)","wv (m/s)","max. wv (m/s)","wd (deg)"]
```

Next, the author parses the file and stores it as a numpy array (note: `float_data` does not contain the timestamps:

```
import numpy as np

float_data = np.zeros((len(lines), len(header) - 1))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
    float_data[i, :] = values
```

This is followed by a normalization step which I am skipping here. So far it is simple. The following step defines a generator which yields a tuple `(samples, targets)` where `samples` is one batch of input data and `targets` is the corresponding array of target temperatures. It takes the following arguments:

1. data: The original array of floating point data, which we just normalized in the code snippet above.
2. lookback: How many timesteps back should our input data go.
3. delay: How many timesteps in the future should our target be.
4. min_index and max_index: Indices in the data array that delimit which timesteps to draw from. This is useful for keeping a segment of the data for validation and another one for testing.
5. shuffle: Whether to shuffle our samples or draw them in chronological order.
6. batch_size: The number of samples per batch.
7. step: The period, in timesteps, at which we sample data. We will set it 6 in order to draw one data point every hour.

   ```
   def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
         shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):

       if max_index is None:
           max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
       i = min_index + lookback
       while 1:
           if shuffle:
                rows = np.random.randint(
                min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
           else:
               if i + batch_size >= max_index:
                   i = min_index + lookback
           rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
           i += len(rows)

           samples = np.zeros((len(rows),
                      lookback // step,
                      data.shape[-1]))
           targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))
           for j, row in enumerate(rows):
               indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
               samples[j] = data[indices]
               targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
           yield samples, targets


    lookback = 1440  # Basically, going back 10 days
    step = 6         # Taking an hourly sample     
    delay = 144      # Want to forecast temperature for the next 24 hours
    batch_size = 128

    train_gen = generator(float_data,
                 lookback=lookback,
                 delay=delay,
                 min_index=0,
                 max_index=200000,
                 shuffle=True,
                 step=step,
                 batch_size=batch_size)

    val_gen = generator(float_data,
               lookback=lookback,
               delay=delay,
               min_index=200001,
               max_index=300000,
               step=step,
               batch_size=batch_size)
   ```

Now, I understand what the code does. Please correct me if I am wrong. It is going to generate input data in the following format:

Each batch will have 128 sequences where each sequence will be 240 long. For example:

Batch 0: [[0-239],[1-240],[2-241],...[127-366]]

Batch 1: [[128-367],...,....                  ]

After this, the author trains a simple model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(lookback // step,   float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                          steps_per_epoch=500,
                          epochs=20,
                          validation_data=val_gen,
                          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

**My questions**

First, I don't understand why is the data being generated in this fashion and fed into the neural network. In other words, why can't the data look like the following?:

Batch 0: [[0-240],[241-479],...........]

Second, in `train_gen` why is the `shuffle` parameter set to `True`? It will cause the data to lose the temporal ordering.

Comment: for the second question: Yes, you data would shuffle.

Comment: on question 1. your code does not understand order, unless you tell it what order you want, perhaps some sorting function is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing of the data starts from 0: since the sequence length is 240 :

> len([0-239]) = 240

And the shuffle is set to True when you want to train , and when you want to evaluate you set it to False

Answer (score 0):

I guess this an example from Deep learning with Python by Francois Chollet. 
Look back is the number of observations from which an observation in samples is built.

Step will define the sequence of observations:

i th observation indexes will be as below :-

```
X -- [i, i+step, i+(2*Step), i+(3*step),...  .. ,(i+look_back/step)] 
y --- [(i+look_back/step)+delay]
```

batch_size = number of such observations

e.g: Input data

```
   [[996.57,  -8.41, 265.01],
   [996.53,  -8.51, 264.91],
   [996.51,  -8.31, 265.12],
   [996.51,  -8.27, 265.15],
   [996.5 ,  -8.05, 265.38],
   [996.5 ,  -7.62, 265.81],
   [996.5 ,  -7.62, 265.81],
   [996.5 ,  -7.91, 265.52],
   [996.53,  -8.43, 264.99],
   [996.62,  -8.76, 264.66],
   [996.62,  -8.88, 264.54],
   [996.63,  -8.85, 264.57],
   [996.74,  -8.83, 264.58],
```

For below parameters:

`lookback = 6
step = 2
delay = 2
batch_size = 3`

Output is:

```
 array([[[996.57,  -8.41, 265.01],
     [996.51,  -8.31, 265.12],
     [996.5 ,  -8.05, 265.38]],

    [[996.53,  -8.51, 264.91],
     [996.51,  -8.27, 265.15],
     [996.5 ,  -7.62, 265.81]],

    [[996.51,  -8.31, 265.12],
     [996.5 ,  -8.05, 265.38],
     [996.5 ,  -7.62, 265.81]]]), array([-8.43, -8.76, -8.88])]
```

Setting shuffle=True does not matter, as observations are always drawn from index-lookback to specific index.

Hourly readings for past 10 days are used for predicting the temperature after 24 hours. So, generating data in this format [[0-240],[241-479],...........] will not give observations for predicting the temperature at (24hrs+10 min)

Answer (score 0):

Each `sample` contains `batch_size` number of sequences and each sequence contains 10 days worth of data i.e. data points from every hour, so that will be `24*10 = 240` data points for 10 days considering 24 data points per day. Hence `[0-239]` has 240 data points corresponding to 10 days worth of data.

The `shuffle` parameter is set to `True` so that the indices chosen for the `rows` numpy array would contain random but contigious indices between the starting and ending points i.e. `min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size` of size `128`.Using this `rows` array we build the `sample`.

Hence summarizing:
The `sample` 3D tensor would have the shape `(128,240,14)` corresponding to `batch_size`,10 days worth of data point considering we took one data point every hour for 10 days due to the `step = 6` and `14` columns of features for every data point.